# How to sort the keySet() of a TreeMap<String, Boolean> with keys containing number?

Tags: java, sorting, treemap, keyset

I'll briefly describe what I did and then show how the result I got, differs from my desired result.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Java code was created in a java online compiler and is executable there without error message in any case.

[Java online compiler, which was used](https://www.w3schools.com/java/tryjava.asp?filename=demo_compiler)

### Short description:

I want to assign a boolean value to every possible combination between row index and column index of a square matrix.
 Only the main diagonal is to be excluded from this. For this I use a `TreeMap <String, Boolean>`

I form the keys of the `TreeMap` by linking {row index + "-"+column index} in a for loop.
 At the beginning, all values of the keys are assigned {false}.

In a second loop, every possible combination of a chosen index `basicL` with other indices (=keys) is to be linked with the Boolean value true (again without values of the main diagonals). As a result, `TreeMap.keySet()` is to be printed in sorted order (sorted by the keys). Example is for `basicL = 4;`

**Illustration of the matrix** *(Boolean true=green, Boolean false=white, excluded=grey):*

[image]

### Java-Code:

```java
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Main {

  static TreeMap<String, Boolean> booleanMap = new TreeMap<>();

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    //all values of symmetric matrix without diagonal axis

    int max = 16;
    int basicL = 4;

    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {

      for (int j = 1; j <= max; j++) {

        if (j != i) {
          booleanMap.put(i + "-" + j, Boolean.valueOf(false));
        }
      }
    }

    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("TreeMap has size:  " + booleanMap.size());
    System.out.println("TreeMap values:    " + booleanMap.values());
    System.out.println("TreeMap keySet:   " + booleanMap.keySet());
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");

    // setting true-conditions

    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {

      if (i != basicL) {

        for (int j = 1; j <= max; j++) {

          if (j == basicL) {

            booleanMap.replace(i + "-" + j, Boolean.valueOf(true));
          }
        }
      }

      if (i == basicL) {

        for (int j = 1; j <= max; j++) {

          if (j != i) {

            booleanMap.replace(i + "-" + j, Boolean.valueOf(true));

          }
        }
      }
    }

    System.out.println("TreeMap values after looping:    " + booleanMap.values());
    System.out.println("TreeMap keySet after looping:    " + booleanMap.keySet());
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
  }
}
```

### **Result achieved for `booleanMap.keySet();`**

```
[1-10, 1-11, 1-12, 1-13, 1-14, 1-15, 1-16, 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 1-5, 1-6, 1-7, 1-8, 1-9, 10-1, 10-11, 10-12, 10-13, 10-14, 10-15, 10-16, 10-2 .... ]
```

### **Desired Result:**

```
[1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 1-5, 1-6, 1-7, 1-8, 1-9, 1-10, 1-11, 1-12, 1-13, 1-14, 1-15, 1-16, 2-1, 2-3, 2-4, 2-5, 2-6, 2-7, 2-8, 2-9, 2-10, 2-11, 2-12 .... ]
```

Comment: Does your result contain the correct key values and your issue is only the wrong sorting?

Comment: Maybe use `String.format("%03d-%03d", i, j)` as the key?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sorting treemap based on key, where key is variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925886/sorting-treemap-based-on-key-where-key-is-variable)

Comment: This is most likely a sorting problem in which the keys do not get interpreted as numbers but strings.

Comment: @Eritrean: Yes, it maps the values to the keys correct and also the TreeMap.size() is equal to a 16×16 matrix without main diagonal. The only problem is, that in the produced output it places e.g. 4-10 before 4-5. I suppose the TreeMap is sorting in an ascending order after each character of the string so a 10 is always placed before a single digit with {2...9} because 1 is smaller.

Comment: @clstrfsck: thanks for your effort, i will try this approach later and give you a feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indexes are sorted lexicographical and not according to the value of the number. A solution would be to prepend zeros (`1-12` -> `001-012`). Another would be to pass a custom comparator to the constructor of TreeMap as shown in the answer by @samabcde.

I suggest that you create a custom class for the position in the matrix. You can implement `compareTo` which lets the `TreeMap` handle the sorting automatically for you. Additionally, you can simplify the second loop significantly and remove the boxing of the booleans.

```
TreeMap<Position, Boolean> booleanMap = new TreeMap<>();

int max = 16;
int basicL = 4;

for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= max; j++) {
        if (j != i) {
            booleanMap.put(new Position(i, j), Boolean.FALSE);
        }
    }
}
```

```
for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= max; j++) {
        if ((i != basicL && j == basicL) || (i == basicL && j != i)) {
            booleanMap.replace(new Position(i, j), Boolean.TRUE);
        }
    }
}
```

```
static class Position implements Comparable<Position> {

    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Position(final int x, final int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final Position o) {
        final int res = Integer.compare(getX(), o.getX());
        return (res != 0) ? res : Integer.compare(getY(), o.getY());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return x + "-" + y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably should have `equals(...)` (and therefore `hashCode()`) for `Comparable` classes.

Answer (score 2):

By default String in TreeMap is sort by [lexicographical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874972/lexicographic-order-in-java). You need a [custom comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Comparator)) in `TreeMap` to sort numerically,

```java
TreeMap<String, Boolean> booleanMap = new TreeMap<>((s1, s2) -> {
    String[] arr1 = s1.split("-");
    String[] arr2 = s2.split("-");
    int i1 = Integer.valueOf(arr1[0]);
    int j1 = Integer.valueOf(arr1[1]);
    int i2 = Integer.valueOf(arr2[0]);
    int j2 = Integer.valueOf(arr2[1]);
    if (i1 != i2) {
        return Integer.compare(i1, i2);
    }
    return Integer.compare(j1, j2);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will try to implement this approach and give you a feedback later,

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help!

I have now tried the approaches from:

1. @ clstrfsck (String.format())
2. @ samabcde (custom comparator)
3. @ matt (create custom class)

Solution approach 1 and 3 I was able to use successfully and generate the desired output.
 Approach 2 I don't quite understand yet, because I still lack the background knowledge of lamda expressions, but maybe I'll get it right.

### Using String.format

I also used an iterator and substrings to generate the key-value pairs and format them back.

```
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

  static TreeMap<String, Boolean> booleanMap = new TreeMap<>();
  
  static String subKey;
  static String subKey2;
  static Integer subKey3;
  static Integer subKey4;
  static String formattedKey;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    //all values of symmetric matrix without diagonal axis

    int max = 16;
    int basicL = 4;

    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {

      for (int j = 1; j <= max; j++) {

        if (j != i) {
          booleanMap.put(String.format("%03d-%03d", i, j), Boolean.FALSE);
        }
      }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {

      if (i != basicL) {

        for (int j = 1; j <= max; j++) {

          if (j == basicL) {

            booleanMap.replace(String.format("%03d-%03d", i, j), Boolean.TRUE);
          }
        }
      }

      if (i == basicL) {

        for (int j = 1; j <= max; j++) {

          if (j != i) {

            booleanMap.replace(String.format("%03d-%03d", i, j), Boolean.TRUE);

          }
        }
      }
    }
    
     Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Boolean>> itr = booleanMap.entrySet().iterator();
     
     System.out.println("------KEY-VALUE PAIRS------");
         
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
             Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry = itr.next();
             
             subKey = entry.getKey().substring(0, 3);
             subKey2 = entry.getKey().substring(4, 7);
             subKey3 = Integer.parseInt(subKey);
             subKey4 = Integer.parseInt(subKey2);
             
             formattedKey = subKey3 +"-"+ subKey4;
             
             System.out.println("Key:" + formattedKey + " ,Value:" + entry.getValue());                     
            
        }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
------KEY-VALUE PAIRS------

Key:1-2 ,Value:false
Key:1-3 ,Value:false
Key:1-4 ,Value:true
Key:1-5 ,Value:false
Key:1-6 ,Value:false
Key:1-7 ,Value:false
Key:1-8 ,Value:false
Key:1-9 ,Value:false
Key:1-10 ,Value:false
Key:1-11 ,Value:false
Key:1-12 ,Value:false
Key:1-13 ,Value:false
Key:1-14 ,Value:false
Key:1-15 ,Value:false
Key:1-16 ,Value:false
Key:2-1 ,Value:false
Key:2-3 ,Value:false
Key:2-4 ,Value:true
Key:2-5 ,Value:false
Key:2-6 ,Value:false
Key:2-7 ,Value:false
Key:2-8 ,Value:false
Key:2-9 ,Value:false
Key:2-10 ,Value:false
Key:2-11 ,Value:false
Key:2-12 ,Value:false
Key:2-13 ,Value:false
Key:2-14 ,Value:false
Key:2-15 ,Value:false
Key:2-16 ,Value:false
Key:3-1 ,Value:false
Key:3-2 ,Value:false
Key:3-4 ,Value:true
Key:3-5 ,Value:false
Key:3-6 ,Value:false
Key:3-7 ,Value:false
Key:3-8 ,Value:false
Key:3-9 ,Value:false
Key:3-10 ,Value:false
Key:3-11 ,Value:false
Key:3-12 ,Value:false
Key:3-13 ,Value:false
Key:3-14 ,Value:false
Key:3-15 ,Value:false
Key:3-16 ,Value:false
Key:4-1 ,Value:true
Key:4-2 ,Value:true
Key:4-3 ,Value:true
Key:4-5 ,Value:true
Key:4-6 ,Value:true
Key:4-7 ,Value:true
Key:4-8 ,Value:true
Key:4-9 ,Value:true
Key:4-10 ,Value:true
Key:4-11 ,Value:true
Key:4-12 ,Value:true
Key:4-13 ,Value:true
Key:4-14 ,Value:true
Key:4-15 ,Value:true
Key:4-16 ,Value:true
Key:5-1 ,Value:false
Key:5-2 ,Value:false
Key:5-3 ,Value:false
Key:5-4 ,Value:true
Key:5-6 ,Value:false
Key:5-7 ,Value:false
Key:5-8 ,Value:false
Key:5-9 ,Value:false
Key:5-10 ,Value:false
Key:5-11 ,Value:false
Key:5-12 ,Value:false
Key:5-13 ,Value:false
Key:5-14 ,Value:false
Key:5-15 ,Value:false
Key:5-16 ,Value:false
Key:6-1 ,Value:false
Key:6-2 ,Value:false
Key:6-3 ,Value:false
Key:6-4 ,Value:true
Key:6-5 ,Value:false
Key:6-7 ,Value:false
Key:6-8 ,Value:false
Key:6-9 ,Value:false
Key:6-10 ,Value:false
Key:6-11 ,Value:false
Key:6-12 ,Value:false
Key:6-13 ,Value:false
Key:6-14 ,Value:false
Key:6-15 ,Value:false
Key:6-16 ,Value:false
Key:7-1 ,Value:false
Key:7-2 ,Value:false
Key:7-3 ,Value:false
Key:7-4 ,Value:true
Key:7-5 ,Value:false
Key:7-6 ,Value:false
Key:7-8 ,Value:false
Key:7-9 ,Value:false
Key:7-10 ,Value:false
Key:7-11 ,Value:false
Key:7-12 ,Value:false
Key:7-13 ,Value:false
Key:7-14 ,Value:false
Key:7-15 ,Value:false
Key:7-16 ,Value:false
Key:8-1 ,Value:false
Key:8-2 ,Value:false
Key:8-3 ,Value:false
Key:8-4 ,Value:true
Key:8-5 ,Value:false
Key:8-6 ,Value:false
Key:8-7 ,Value:false
Key:8-9 ,Value:false
Key:8-10 ,Value:false
Key:8-11 ,Value:false
Key:8-12 ,Value:false
Key:8-13 ,Value:false
Key:8-14 ,Value:false
Key:8-15 ,Value:false
Key:8-16 ,Value:false
Key:9-1 ,Value:false
Key:9-2 ,Value:false
Key:9-3 ,Value:false
Key:9-4 ,Value:true
Key:9-5 ,Value:false
Key:9-6 ,Value:false
Key:9-7 ,Value:false
Key:9-8 ,Value:false
Key:9-10 ,Value:false
Key:9-11 ,Value:false
Key:9-12 ,Value:false
Key:9-13 ,Value:false
Key:9-14 ,Value:false
Key:9-15 ,Value:false
Key:9-16 ,Value:false
Key:10-1 ,Value:false
Key:10-2 ,Value:false
Key:10-3 ,Value:false
Key:10-4 ,Value:true
Key:10-5 ,Value:false
Key:10-6 ,Value:false
Key:10-7 ,Value:false
Key:10-8 ,Value:false
Key:10-9 ,Value:false
Key:10-11 ,Value:false
Key:10-12 ,Value:false
Key:10-13 ,Value:false
Key:10-14 ,Value:false
Key:10-15 ,Value:false
Key:10-16 ,Value:false
Key:11-1 ,Value:false
Key:11-2 ,Value:false
Key:11-3 ,Value:false
Key:11-4 ,Value:true
Key:11-5 ,Value:false
Key:11-6 ,Value:false
Key:11-7 ,Value:false
Key:11-8 ,Value:false
Key:11-9 ,Value:false
Key:11-10 ,Value:false
Key:11-12 ,Value:false
Key:11-13 ,Value:false
Key:11-14 ,Value:false
Key:11-15 ,Value:false
Key:11-16 ,Value:false
Key:12-1 ,Value:false
Key:12-2 ,Value:false
Key:12-3 ,Value:false
Key:12-4 ,Value:true
Key:12-5 ,Value:false
Key:12-6 ,Value:false
Key:12-7 ,Value:false
Key:12-8 ,Value:false
Key:12-9 ,Value:false
Key:12-10 ,Value:false
Key:12-11 ,Value:false
Key:12-13 ,Value:false
Key:12-14 ,Value:false
Key:12-15 ,Value:false
Key:12-16 ,Value:false
Key:13-1 ,Value:false
Key:13-2 ,Value:false
Key:13-3 ,Value:false
Key:13-4 ,Value:true
Key:13-5 ,Value:false
Key:13-6 ,Value:false
Key:13-7 ,Value:false
Key:13-8 ,Value:false
Key:13-9 ,Value:false
Key:13-10 ,Value:false
Key:13-11 ,Value:false
Key:13-12 ,Value:false
Key:13-14 ,Value:false
Key:13-15 ,Value:false
Key:13-16 ,Value:false
Key:14-1 ,Value:false
Key:14-2 ,Value:false
Key:14-3 ,Value:false
Key:14-4 ,Value:true
Key:14-5 ,Value:false
Key:14-6 ,Value:false
Key:14-7 ,Value:false
Key:14-8 ,Value:false
Key:14-9 ,Value:false
Key:14-10 ,Value:false
Key:14-11 ,Value:false
Key:14-12 ,Value:false
Key:14-13 ,Value:false
Key:14-15 ,Value:false
Key:14-16 ,Value:false
Key:15-1 ,Value:false
Key:15-2 ,Value:false
Key:15-3 ,Value:false
Key:15-4 ,Value:true
Key:15-5 ,Value:false
Key:15-6 ,Value:false
Key:15-7 ,Value:false
Key:15-8 ,Value:false
Key:15-9 ,Value:false
Key:15-10 ,Value:false
Key:15-11 ,Value:false
Key:15-12 ,Value:false
Key:15-13 ,Value:false
Key:15-14 ,Value:false
Key:15-16 ,Value:false
Key:16-1 ,Value:false
Key:16-2 ,Value:false
Key:16-3 ,Value:false
Key:16-4 ,Value:true
Key:16-5 ,Value:false
Key:16-6 ,Value:false
Key:16-7 ,Value:false
Key:16-8 ,Value:false
Key:16-9 ,Value:false
Key:16-10 ,Value:false
Key:16-11 ,Value:false
Key:16-12 ,Value:false
Key:16-13 ,Value:false
Key:16-14 ,Value:false
Key:16-15 ,Value:false
```

### Create custom class (best working solution for me)

```
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.lang.*;

public class Main {

  static TreeMap<Position, Boolean> booleanMap = new TreeMap<>();
   
  static public class Position implements Comparable<Position> {

    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Position(final int x, final int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final Position o) {
        final int res = Integer.compare(getX(), o.getX());
        return (res != 0) ? res : Integer.compare(getY(), o.getY());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return x + "-" + y;
    }
}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  
    //all values of symmetric matrix without diagonal axis

    int max = 16;
    int basicL = 4;

   for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
     for (int j = 1; j <= max; j++) {
        if (j != i) {
            booleanMap.put(new Position(i, j), Boolean.FALSE);
          }
         }
        }

    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("TreeMap has size:  " + booleanMap.size());
    System.out.println("TreeMap values:    " + booleanMap.values());
    System.out.println("TreeMap keySet:    " + booleanMap.keySet());
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");

    // setting true-conditions

   for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= max; j++) {
        if ((i != basicL && j == basicL) || (i == basicL && j != i)) {
            booleanMap.replace(new Position(i, j), Boolean.TRUE);
        }
    }
}  

    System.out.println("TreeMap values after looping:    " + booleanMap.values());
    System.out.println("TreeMap keySet after looping:    " + booleanMap.keySet());
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
    
  }
}
```

**Result:**

---

```
TreeMap has size:  240
TreeMap values:    [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
TreeMap keySet:    [1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 1-5, 1-6, 1-7, 1-8, 1-9, 1-10, 1-11, 1-12, 1-13, 1-14, 1-15, 1-16, 2-1, 2-3, 2-4, 2-5, 2-6, 2-7, 2-8, 2-9, 2-10, 2-11, 2-12, 2-13, 2-14, 2-15, 2-16, 3-1, 3-2, 3-4, 3-5, 3-6, 3-7, 3-8, 3-9, 3-10, 3-11, 3-12, 3-13, 3-14, 3-15, 3-16, 4-1, 4-2, 4-3, 4-5, 4-6, 4-7, 4-8, 4-9, 4-10, 4-11, 4-12, 4-13, 4-14, 4-15, 4-16, 5-1, 5-2, 5-3, 5-4, 5-6, 5-7, 5-8, 5-9, 5-10, 5-11, 5-12, 5-13, 5-14, 5-15, 5-16, 6-1, 6-2, 6-3, 6-4, 6-5, 6-7, 6-8, 6-9, 6-10, 6-11, 6-12, 6-13, 6-14, 6-15, 6-16, 7-1, 7-2, 7-3, 7-4, 7-5, 7-6, 7-8, 7-9, 7-10, 7-11, 7-12, 7-13, 7-14, 7-15, 7-16, 8-1, 8-2, 8-3, 8-4, 8-5, 8-6, 8-7, 8-9, 8-10, 8-11, 8-12, 8-13, 8-14, 8-15, 8-16, 9-1, 9-2, 9-3, 9-4, 9-5, 9-6, 9-7, 9-8, 9-10, 9-11, 9-12, 9-13, 9-14, 9-15, 9-16, 10-1, 10-2, 10-3, 10-4, 10-5, 10-6, 10-7, 10-8, 10-9, 10-11, 10-12, 10-13, 10-14, 10-15, 10-16, 11-1, 11-2, 11-3, 11-4, 11-5, 11-6, 11-7, 11-8, 11-9, 11-10, 11-12, 11-13, 11-14, 11-15, 11-16, 12-1, 12-2, 12-3, 12-4, 12-5, 12-6, 12-7, 12-8, 12-9, 12-10, 12-11, 12-13, 12-14, 12-15, 12-16, 13-1, 13-2, 13-3, 13-4, 13-5, 13-6, 13-7, 13-8, 13-9, 13-10, 13-11, 13-12, 13-14, 13-15, 13-16, 14-1, 14-2, 14-3, 14-4, 14-5, 14-6, 14-7, 14-8, 14-9, 14-10, 14-11, 14-12, 14-13, 14-15, 14-16, 15-1, 15-2, 15-3, 15-4, 15-5, 15-6, 15-7, 15-8, 15-9, 15-10, 15-11, 15-12, 15-13, 15-14, 15-16, 16-1, 16-2, 16-3, 16-4, 16-5, 16-6, 16-7, 16-8, 16-9, 16-10, 16-11, 16-12, 16-13, 16-14, 16-15]
-----------------------------------------------------
TreeMap values after looping:    [false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
TreeMap keySet after looping:    [1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 1-5, 1-6, 1-7, 1-8, 1-9, 1-10, 1-11, 1-12, 1-13, 1-14, 1-15, 1-16, 2-1, 2-3, 2-4, 2-5, 2-6, 2-7, 2-8, 2-9, 2-10, 2-11, 2-12, 2-13, 2-14, 2-15, 2-16, 3-1, 3-2, 3-4, 3-5, 3-6, 3-7, 3-8, 3-9, 3-10, 3-11, 3-12, 3-13, 3-14, 3-15, 3-16, 4-1, 4-2, 4-3, 4-5, 4-6, 4-7, 4-8, 4-9, 4-10, 4-11, 4-12, 4-13, 4-14, 4-15, 4-16, 5-1, 5-2, 5-3, 5-4, 5-6, 5-7, 5-8, 5-9, 5-10, 5-11, 5-12, 5-13, 5-14, 5-15, 5-16, 6-1, 6-2, 6-3, 6-4, 6-5, 6-7, 6-8, 6-9, 6-10, 6-11, 6-12, 6-13, 6-14, 6-15, 6-16, 7-1, 7-2, 7-3, 7-4, 7-5, 7-6, 7-8, 7-9, 7-10, 7-11, 7-12, 7-13, 7-14, 7-15, 7-16, 8-1, 8-2, 8-3, 8-4, 8-5, 8-6, 8-7, 8-9, 8-10, 8-11, 8-12, 8-13, 8-14, 8-15, 8-16, 9-1, 9-2, 9-3, 9-4, 9-5, 9-6, 9-7, 9-8, 9-10, 9-11, 9-12, 9-13, 9-14, 9-15, 9-16, 10-1, 10-2, 10-3, 10-4, 10-5, 10-6, 10-7, 10-8, 10-9, 10-11, 10-12, 10-13, 10-14, 10-15, 10-16, 11-1, 11-2, 11-3, 11-4, 11-5, 11-6, 11-7, 11-8, 11-9, 11-10, 11-12, 11-13, 11-14, 11-15, 11-16, 12-1, 12-2, 12-3, 12-4, 12-5, 12-6, 12-7, 12-8, 12-9, 12-10, 12-11, 12-13, 12-14, 12-15, 12-16, 13-1, 13-2, 13-3, 13-4, 13-5, 13-6, 13-7, 13-8, 13-9, 13-10, 13-11, 13-12, 13-14, 13-15, 13-16, 14-1, 14-2, 14-3, 14-4, 14-5, 14-6, 14-7, 14-8, 14-9, 14-10, 14-11, 14-12, 14-13, 14-15, 14-16, 15-1, 15-2, 15-3, 15-4, 15-5, 15-6, 15-7, 15-8, 15-9, 15-10, 15-11, 15-12, 15-13, 15-14, 15-16, 16-1, 16-2, 16-3, 16-4, 16-5, 16-6, 16-7, 16-8, 16-9, 16-10, 16-11, 16-12, 16-13, 16-14, 16-15]
-----------------------------------------------------
```